# Why doesn't TypeScript complain about incorrect values in Partial types with computed keys?

Tags: typescript

Why does TypeScript allow the following?

```
interface SubType {
    key: keyof MyType
}

interface MyType {
    a: string
    b: string
}

const container: SubType = { key: 'a' }

const test: Partial<MyType> = {
    [container.key]: 3
}
```

It correctly complains when `key` isn't actually a key in `MyType`, but it doesn't seem to care what I set the value to, even though `MyType` can only have `string` values.

[Link to TS playrground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%20%20%20%20interface%20SubType%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20key%3A%20keyof%20MyType%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20MyType%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20a%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20b%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20container%3A%20SubType%20%3D%20%7B%20key%3A%20'a'%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20test%3A%20Partial%3CMyType%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Bcontainer.key%5D%3A%203%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A)

Comment: I did got an error that number not fit string. Environment: node 8.10, ts-node^7.0.0, typescript^3.0.1, target es6

Comment: You're right, let me see if I can make this match what I'm seeing better.

Comment: Just updated it. Seems like it is related to the indexed key being a field of an object in some way.

Comment: To me, the `[container.key]` is more like runtime value, which is not cleared for TS.

Comment: `const container = {key:'x'}` can compile too.

Comment: The current question is missing the definition of `container`.

Comment: @IngoBürk `const container: SubType = { key: 'a' }` is in the example. Are you sure?

Comment: @TKJohn That isn't true as far as I can see. If you attempt to set key to `x` in `container` then it won't compile. If you attempt to add `x: 3` to `test` it won't compile.

Comment: Yes. And this is what I want to say. The `container.key` expression would only be resolved to a value in Runtime. So TS won't know what the value it would be. And cannot do check to it.

Comment: @TKJohn That isn't true either. First off, the object can be defined completely as a constant and be available at compile time and this will still happen. Second, if you replace `container` with `const container : { key: 'x' } = { key: 'x' }` then it properly complains about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the type of a computed property name is not a singleton (here the type of `container.key` is `"a" | "b"`), then TypeScript isn't smart enough to validate the value at all.  See the `checkObjectLiteral` function in [`src/compiler/checker.ts`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/compiler/checker.ts?raw=true).  Note that if you comment out the `b: string` member of `MyType`, so that the type of `container.key` becomes `"a"`, then the expected error appears.  There's a little more information in [this issue report](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21030).

Comment: That's unfortunate. I'll have to tell people to declare the values as a const with a type annotation until that changes I suppose.